# Plotting graphs from different years in one graph (datetime64)

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have the following problem: I want to combine graphs from various years in one plot. To explain you more about my problem I made the hereunder simplified problem.

```
# packages    
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Here I make a simplified dataframe which i want to plot

```
data = {'Dates': ['02-04-2014', '18-08-2014', '05-03-2014', '06-06-2014', '05-08-2013', '06-11-2013', '03-01-2013', '12-02-2013'], 'Values':
      [7, 8, 11, 3, 6, 1, 8, 13]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

This is important for  me because it is the format I work with in my problem

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
```

Here I do the plotting

```
years = sorted([i for i in df['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x.year).unique()])
for i in years:
    df1 = df[(df['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x.year) == i)]
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by = ['Dates'])
    plt.show()
```

This returns in this case two separate line plots, one for the year 2013 and one for 2014. I want these combined in one graph. So, that i get one grap with a legend for the year.

Hope you can help!